# How to show image while page is loading in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview, uiwebview

I'm beginner in swift and Xcode and want to know how to make an image appears while page finish loading in UIWebView,like when you enter a new website,image start appear on screen in webview

Comment: What image? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry,I'm new in here.Image like ad,when you load website ad appears in bottom or other side it doesn't matters where,i only want to know the code that let image or ad show when page finish loading

Comment: Are you looking for HTML or Swift? I'm still not sure what you mean... Maybe some example screenshots would help? See [ask] and the [help]

Comment: In swift of course,thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any loader meanwhile the website loads, like `MBProgressHUD` or any other progress bar.

And if you are willing to show an custom image over a screen while loading then you can handle that in following delegate methods:

say you have take any custom image or View  called **loadingView**

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!) {
**loadingView**.viewWithTag(1)?.hidden = true 
print("Webview fail with error \(error)");
}

**func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -&gt; Bool {**
return true;
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
**loadingView**.viewWithTag(1)?.hidden = false 
print("Webview started Loading")
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
**loadingView**.viewWithTag(1)?.hidden = true 
print("Webview did finish load")
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what i needed.